# Can someone translate this code into Pseudo Code or something I can understand?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am not very familiar with regex(s) and would like somebody to put this into something that I will be able to understand?  As in, outline what each part of the regex is doing

`re.compile(r'ATG((?:[ACTG]{3})+?)(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)')`

So far, this is what I have come up with:
`re.compile` is a regex method... or something along those lines

`r'` is simply needed in regex

After that, I'm not too sure...

Searches for a piece in the string `ATG`

`?:[ACTG]{3}` searches for a piece of the string containing the characters `A` `C` `T` `G` within the string (does the order of these matter?) that is `{3}` three characters long.

`+?` something about going at least once, but minimal times...?  What would part of code would be going at least once, but minimal times?

`?:` searches for `TAG|TAA|TGA`within the string.  Once it finds these, what does happens?
Would I be able to do something like
`key_words = "TAG TAA TGA".replace(" ", "|")` so that I can have a whole long list without having to type of `|` a bunch of times if I have  over 100 substrings?
I would then format this to something like this:
`...(?:key_words)')`

Examples and simple explanations always work wonders - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rR4aE7/1) to have it explained step by step.

[image]